# generating parametric and non-parametric bootstrap samples in R

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R, I am finding it a bit difficult to generate parametric bootstrap samples using the boot function. I have already calculated the mle parameters for weibull distribution, now I need to generate 500 replicates.

I have done this so far

```
#givenData is of this form--->  int [1:2546] 69 49 40 33 33 .....
library("boot")
library("MASS")
library("fitdistrplus")
library("actuar")


statFunc = function(d, i)
{
  d2 = d
  return(mean(d2[i]))
}

#givenData is the observed data to which I am fitting a weibull distribution
fitWeibull = fitdist(givenData, "weibull")
mleParams = c(fitWeibull$estimate["shape"], fitWeibull$estimate["scale"])


#mleParams is a list - mleParams[1] is shape, mleParams[2] is scale
pBootFunc = function(d, mle)
{
  out <- d
  out$param <- rweibull(length(out), mle[1], mle[2])
  out
}

# data has two columns - "serialNum" and "pre" (pre has integer values)
pbootstrap = boot(givenData, statFunc, R = 2, sim = "parametric", ran.gen = pBootFunc, mle = mleParams)

pVal = boot.array(pbootstrap, indices = T)
```

When I run this, I ger "Error in boot.array(pbootstrap, indices = T) : 
  array cannot be found for parametric bootstrap"

I want pVal to contain the bootstrap replicates. How do I do this?

Comment: Capitalization must be consistent. You do not show `statFunc` so this code is incomplete. Positional matching for arguments in functions passed to `boot` must have the first argument as a dataframe and the second argument as an index. Please review and run the examples on the `?boot` help page. If you do not edit your question to include code for statFunc this question will be closed as not capable of debugging without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, I think I modified all the things you mentioned, I am still getting the same error

Comment: You are supposed to use the index inside your boot-statistic-function. At the moment you are not. I say again: read the help page and work through the examples there. (I get an error related to your continuing failure to include full code: "object 'mleParams' not found"

Comment: I put the complete code and I am using the index inside the statistic function. Now it is reproducible, and I am getting the same error. How do I get the samples now?

Comment: Still no data. Still not reproducible. Your givenData is described as having two columns but that should have thrown an error from `fitdistr` (which you also misspelled.)

Answer (score 2):

1) for parametric bootstrap
Since you already know the mle parameters of the distribution, you can use "[rweibull](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Weibull.html)" to generate random deviates. And you can use a for loop to generate these variates 500 times

```
library(boot)

for( i in 1:500 )
{
    currentIterVariates = rweibull(length(out), mleShape, mleScale)
}
```

If you want to store all the 500 samples, initialize a matrix and then store the values there.

2) non-parametric bootstrap (I'm writing this because of the title of your question)

```
library(boot)

#assume func is written, it will be similar to your statFunc

npBootstrap = boot(data, func, R=500)
samples = boot.array(npBootstrap, indices = T)

#the required resamples will be present in samples matrix (500 x length(data) matrix)
```

Comment: Your for-loop is not good advice for a newbie. You are over-writing `currentIterVariates` with the value from `rweibull` 499 times. Pretty much all of the `r*` functions deliver a vector of the  length specified by the first argument. Perhaps you should learn to use `replicate` if what you wanted was 500 realizations of length-500 vectors. (It wasn't clear what you did expect.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpfull code for a parametric bootstrap of an indicated normal distribution:
I made a percentile of the values

```
B <- 1000
n <- 50
bs <- rep(NA, B)
for (b in 1:B) {
sample <- rnorm(n, mean=earlier.estimate.of.mean, sd= earlier.estimate.of.sd)
m <- fitdistr(sample, "normal")
bs[b] <- m$estimate[1]+m$estimate[2]*qnorm(0.99)
```

You can also do this with mvrnorm but then you have to use the covariance matrix

Comment: Is you want a nonparamatric, you should make your sample from the observed data